# Modifying methods in class hierarchy

Tags: python

So I have a Polynomial superclass and a Quadratic subclass and I want to modify the **add** operator so instead of returning a polynomial object it returns a Quadratic object how would I do this?

Here is this Polynomial **add** and it returns a Polynomial object

```
def __add__(self, other):
        newPoly = Polynomial()
        for i in range(len(self.coeffs)):
            newPoly.addterm(self.coeffs[i][0], self.coeffs[i][1])
            newPoly.addterm(other.coeffs[i][0], other.coeffs[i][1])
        return (newPoly)
```

and this is the quadratic class:

```
class Quadratic(Polynomial):
    def __init__(self, quad, lin, con):
        Polynomial.__init__(self, (quad, 2), (lin, 1), (con, 0))
```

So how can I modify the **add** operator so it returns a Quadratic object instead of a Polynomial?

Comment: Adding something to a Quadratic isn't necessarily going to be a Quadratic; it might be a higher degree, or the quadratic term might cancel out.  Quadratic looks more like a special constructor for the Polynomial class, than something that should be a subclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looked weired to me that you are trying to return a subclass's instance from a superclass's method, since superclass usually means a more general concept.

I think you can just call the Quadratic's constructor with appropriate arguments passed in.

```
def __add__(self, other):
        newQuad = Quad(0,0,0)
        for order,(c1,c2) in enumerate(zip(self.coeffs,other.other)):
            newQuad.addterm(c1[0], c1[1])
            newQuad.addterm(c2[0], c2[1])
            if order == 1:
                break

        return (newQuad)
```

I've modified your code by a more readable, Pythonic way.

To be honest, I don't think there is any necessity to derive a subclass for each order, you can simpy record the information of order by an additional attribute for an example.

Finally, it is not recommended to write the superclass's name explicitly in subclass's code since it would reduce the flexibility.Python has a keyword called "super" which can let you invoke superclass's method without through it's name directly, but there are a lot of details about the keyword, so you might want to study the documentation by yourself.